# Encoded slashes break route in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have the following route in my routes.php

`Router::connect('/:lang/detail/:id/*', array('controller' => 'main', 'action' => 'detail'), array('lang' => '[a-z]{3}'));`

and the following URL works

http://www.cyclistsroadmap.com/eng/detail/1380/Ferguson++119th/

But the following does not:

http://www.cyclistsroadmap.com/eng/detail/1380/Ferguson+%2f+119th/
(%2f is url encoded slash)

It would seem to me that greedy star should take anything but it doesn't seem to like the encoded slash in there. Is this something that I am doing wrong or is this a genuine bug in Cakephp?

Comment: what's the action method's signature?

Comment: what is "action method's signature"?

Comment: Actually, you should post your code and the results you got.

Comment: What code do you want me to post? I added the route in question and the incoming is a link.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have enabled the AllowEncodedSlashes directive in Apache:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes on
```

More info can be found here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Comment: I don't have access to the httpd.config. Can this be set from inside the htaccess or with cakePHP somewhere?

Comment: @paullb it doesn't seem to be able to be set in `.htaccess` from the research I've done, disappointing...

Answer (score 3):

Although this may not apply to your situation, I had a similar problem that I fixed in the following way.

We keep a URL for a tree like set of pages with it's path that get's updated on save. Ex:

```
Name          | Path
Home          | /
- Support     | /support
-- Legal      | /support/legal
-- Privacy    | /support/privacy
- About       | /about
-- Who We Are | /about/who-we-are
```

We then pass the path as an argument to our controller. The regular Router::* methods will encode the slashes in these. What we do instead is the following:

```
$redirect = explode('/', $path);
$redirect['controller'] = 'my_controller';
$redirect['action']     = 'my_action';
$this->redirect($redirect);
```

This let's cake re-encode the slashes for me. Then you can re-assemble them in the controller

```
$path = implode('/', $this->request->params['pass']);
```